# spark-submit python file and getting No module Found

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
 spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --deploy-mode cluster test.py
```

end up with error

> import pandas as pd ImportError: No module named pandas

this is the only error I see.

using anaconda python distribution 2.7
`PYSPARK_VENV]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` location has pandas.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is your error in details, please ? Maybe an error warning snippet and the version of python and spark you are using would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether pandas installed in **[PYSPARK_VENV]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/** folder. Looks like you are executing your pyspark application on another python interpreter. Please ensure that you have installed pandas package for that interpreter.

You can use Anaconda for managing python packages in these knida situations.

Comment: pandas are installed, I have no problem using pysaprk and I have issues with python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Setting PYSPARK_PYTHON path should solve this:

check the pyspark path using: `which pyspark`

`export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/pyspark/path/from/above`